# How do I reinstall graphics drivers after swapping my nVidia for an ATI?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, ati, graphics

A highly foolish thing to do, i know, but now the poor old pc is stuck

- bios & grub start ok
- booting into *recovery mode* is possible, can get a root shell
- botting normal mode gets as far as the splash screen (not the login screen)
- but then it hangs, with a black screen, and the monitors switch off saying no signal

I've looked at my Xorg.conf and it still refers to NVida being the main device (that was the old card, now i've put in an ati radeon)

Any tips on how to get everything reconfigured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `xorg.conf` file leaving a backup file behind

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak
```

Remove the nvidia drivers completely

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-current
```

Install the ATI drivers from the Ubuntu repos

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: If you get stuck at any point on this or if it does not work as expected please drop a comment.

Comment: thanks!  As it turns out, I managed to figure it out for myself, and your instructions are almost exactly what I did :-)