# Pre-upgrade questions about upgrading from ATI 4870 to nVidia GTX650 on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, ati

I'm upgrading my computer's video card. I've been using the open source 'radeon' driver with an AMD HD4870. My new card is a nVidia GTX650 that I'm planning on using the proprietary drivers with.

I know if you're using the flgrx drivers for ati/amd, you have to remove those first before installing your new card. Since I'm using the radeon open source drivers, how do I go about making sure I don't reboot into an unworking display? Do I need to remove or otherwise make some sort of configuration prior to removing the HD4870 and installing the GTX650?

Thanks!

Comment: While not a duplicate, [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/85580/12864) describes the exact opposite process (NVIDIA -> ATI). It's a pretty good starting point for solving your problem. I've never changed video card brands so I'm afraid I can't offer more help than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're switching from AMD to NVIDIA, you have several ways of doing this:

1 - Poweroff PC, put new card, remove old drivers, install new drivers

By booting the new card without the new drivers installed, will get you to a console terminal, no problem there, simply remove old drivers and install new ones.

2 - You can go to init 3 with the PC turned on, remove old drivers install new ones, shutdown and then insert new graphic card.

Comment: Then a new question. How do I go about removing the 'radeon' driver that my amd/ati card is currently using. I've been searching here and other forums, but everything assumes you're using flgrx with your amd/ati card. I am not.

Comment: If the module is beeing used, i don't think it will let you remove it. You can simply remove a module by `rmmod radeon`

Comment: Just to make sure I got it straight:

I could boot my computer into init3, run `rmmod radeon`, and then install my nvidia drivers.

That seem like a good direction?

Comment: Yes. You can give it a go

Comment: This ended up working like a charm. After installing my new nVidia card I booted into recovery from the Grub screen, then chose to drop into a root command line. From there I ran 'rmmod radeon' and rebooted. Ubuntu fired up, I was able to then install the nVidia proprietary drivers which installed just fine and are working well.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You can accept the answer as the correct and upvote it, so other users will find it usefull